# Is there a way to debug installer executable created using installshield universal?

Tags: windows, installshield

I have created a windows executable with some custom actions and some UI stuffs.

I am facing a strange behavior with the installable.

I tried probing through the code and kracking the installer as much as I can, but I did not find any idea why the strange behavior is available.

So, I wanted to debug the installer at every point of code execution in the Custom Action for which I tried writing those values I require to a logger. But unfortunately my logger will get created after the installation at which point I will not be in a position to run it again.

So, can anyone suggest how to debug it while the installable is under execution?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried but couldn't get a debugger working with Installshield universal.

My workaround was to add a lot of debugging messages and to use VMware. Install VMware and create the test machine as a virtual server. I configured the virtual server with all the prerequisites, rebooted it and then ran a snapshot.

After the snap shot I'd run the install script, wait for the errors and the log files. Then  I'd use the VMware 'revert to snapshot' function to go back to a clean instance of the test server and start investigating the error messages from the logs.

Comment: Yes. I too could debug only with debuggin messages. Also, that i was logging it to a log file such that i can track the happening and keep it for later.